# Flex 4 Alternative to partAdded() in an ItemRenderer

Tags: flex4, itemrenderer

I'm working on an application which uses a List and some itemRenderers. I have a button displayed in the "selected" state automatically set by the List component. This button is supposed to dispatch a custom event when clicked. Problem is, I don't know how to add my event listener, and I don't want to use 'click=""' because it's kinda dirty IMHO.
/
If it was a SkinnableContainer, I could override the partAdded() but I couldn't find anything similar in the ItemRenderer or the DataRenderer.

Any hints?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the button creationComplete event to add the listener.

Or, for complex itemRenderers I usually create my own that extends SkinnableComponent and implements IDataRenderer.  You can then override partAdded/partRemoved functions. Note that you will also need to define and support the skin states (hovered, selected...).

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to use SkinnableComponent, so I finally created my own component which implements IItemRenderer, and voilà :)
Thanks !